# CSS settings not working correctly in IE 9

Tags: html, css

I am setting the top and left attributes of an element but it doesn't work correctly in IE 9. However it is working fine in Google Chrome and Firefox.

So I want to use some filter for IE in CSS that would explicitly set the values for IE.
How can I do that?

For example, like Ii use this filter:

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at browser-specific conditonal comments - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 3):

according to [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient), IE9 does not support gradient

Answer (score 1):

Try this may work for you

```css
#myDiv {
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFE6E6E6', GradientType=0);

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
```

This may help you http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this gradient generator with IE9 support also :- http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

review the http://abouthalf.com/2011/10/04/updated-ie9-gradients-with-rounded-corners/ link . May this solve your problem